# Чи є нормативним вживання плеонастичного словосполученння "експонат виставки"

Tags: вживання-слів

Вітаю! Сьогодні побачила афішу з написом "...експонати виставки.....".Чи є нормативним вживання цього словосполучення?Знайшла неоднозначну інформацію про це. Одні ввважають, що це нормативно:["Тавтологія і плеоназм: зі знаком «плюс» чи знаком «мінус»](http://tverdyna.ucoz.ua/blog/v_jacheslav_vasilchenko_pro_kulturu_movi/2015-04-08-30) , інші-ненормативно:[“Що таке мовленнєва надмірність і мовленнєва недостатність?”](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/16.php)                                        Якщо це словосполучення можна вживати, то як розрізнити, які плеонастичні словосполучення є нормативними/ненормативними. Просто запам'ятати?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сучасний [словник української мови](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=25747&page=858) подає таку інформацію:

> ЕКСПОНА́Т, а, ч. Предмет, виставлений для огляду в музеї або на виставці.
>
> – Таке дрантя – у музей? – скептично запитав Славко. – Аякже. Вбрання дітей Землі! – захоплено мовив Рон. – Та це буде найкращий експонат нашого музею (О. Бердник)
>
> ВИ́СТАВКА, и, ж. Публічний показ спеціально підібраних предметів і місце цього показу.
>   // Сукупність предметів, виставлених для огляду.
>
> Учні представили виставку своїх малюнків із музичної тематики та взяли участь у вікторині (із журн.).

З першого погляду це здається тавтологією, однак відмінність у тому, що експонат — це може бути і один предмет, а виставка — це їх сукупність.  Отже, так, нормативно використовувати таку конструкцію.

Щодо запам’ятовування, то у цій же статті [“Що таке мовленнєва надмірність і мовленнєва недостатність?"](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/16.php) зауважила, що автори пишуть так:

> Деякі плеонастичні словосполучення закріпилися в мові й не вважаються сьогодні порушенням лексичних норм. Це такі вислови, як букіністична книга (від фр. bouquin — стара книга), **експонат виставки** (від лат. expono — виставляю напоказ), монументальний пам’ятник (від лат. monumentum — знак пам’яті), реальна дійсність (від лат. realis — дійсний).

Таким чином їх просто потрібно запам’ятати.

Comment: «Однак відмінність у тому, що експонат — це може бути і один предмет, а виставка — це їх сукупність» — я думаю, Ви неправильно інтерпретували, в чому тут тавтологія. Тавтологія не в тому, що експонат і виставка начебто означають одне й те саме (ні, вони означають різне), а в тому, що саме слово експонат (за думкою Васильченка) вже позначає саме «предмет виставки», тому (за його думкою) варто казати або «експонат» (без слова виставка, бо «експонат» уже має на увазі приналежність до виставки), або «предмет виставки». (Не кажу, що я з цим згоден — бо зараз експонати можуть бути не на виставках.)